# PHP Array efficiency vs mySQL query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a MySQL table with about 9.5K rows, these won't change much but I may slowly add to them.

I have a process where if someone scans a barcode I have to check if that barcode matches a value in this table.  What would be the fastest way to accomplish this? I must mention there is no pattern to these values

Here Are Some Thoughts

1. Ajax call to PHP file to query MySQL table ( my thoughts would this would be slowest )
2. Load this MySQL table into an array on log in.  Then when scanning Ajax call to PHP file to check the array
3. Load this table into an array on log in.  When viewing the scanning page somehow load that array into a JavaScript array and check with JavaScript. (this seems to me to be the fastest because it eliminates Ajax call and MySQL Query. Would it be efficient to split into smaller arrays so I don't lag the server & browser?)

Comment: Best to benchmark. But with good indices, I expect that doing the query each time will be quickest. In any event, you're practising premature optimization. This is not likely to be a rate limiting step. I have a jQuery/PHP/MySQL autocomplete against an ~100K table and it's plenty fast.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't cache stuff in PHP session variables, since these are written to disk on each request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, I'd never load the entire table for anything. All I'd do is make an AJAX request back to a PHP gateway that then queries the database, and returns the result (or nothing). It can be very fast (as it only depends on the latency) and you can cache that result heavily (via [**memcached**](http://memcached.org/), or something like it).

There's really no reason to ever load the entire array for "validation"...

Answer (score 2):

Much faster to used a **well indexed** MySQL table, then to look through an array for something.

But in the end it all depends on what you *really* want to do with the data.

Comment: Its only for validation.  If it validates then I insert into a different MySQL table

Comment: I understand some of the reasons not to but this is a weird scenario.  This process is used on a local setting where we control browser and community who uses it

Comment: @Robert Client validation makes sense if you aren't sending the data to the server. Also, if you plan to use data only locally, local arrays will probably be a faster solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentions your table contain around 9.5K of data. There is no logic to load data on login or scanning page.

Better to index your table and do a ajax call whenever required.

Best of Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

While 9.5 K rows are not that much, the related amount of data would need some time to transfer.

Therefore - and in general - I'd propose to **run validation of values on the server side**. AJAX is the right technology to do this quite easily.

Loading all 9.5 K rows only to find one specific row, is definitely a waste of resources. Run a **SELECT-query** for the single value.

**Exposing PHP-functionality at the client-side / AJAX**

Have a look at the [xajax project](http://www.xajax-project.org), which allows to expose whole PHP classes or single methods as AJAX method at the client side. Moreover, xajax helps during the exchange of parameters between client and server.

**Indexing to be searched attributes**

Please ensure, that the **column, which holds the barcode value, is [indexed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)**. In case the verification process tends to be slow, look out for [MySQL table scans](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html).

**Avoiding table scans**

To avoid table scans and keep your queries run fast, do use **fixed sized fields**. E.g. VARCHAR() besides  other types makes queries slower, since rows no longer have a fixed size. No fixed-sized tables effectively prevent the database to easily predict the location of the next row of the result set. **Therefore, you e.g. CHAR(20) instead of VARCHAR().**

**Finally: Security!**

Don't forget, that any data transferred to the client side may expose sensitive data. While your 9.5 K rows may not get rendered by client's browser, the rows do exist in the generated HTML-page. Using *Show source* any user would be able to **figure out all valid numbers**.

Exposing valid barcode values may or may not be a security problem in your project context.

*PS: While not related to your question, I'd propose to use [PHPexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) for reading or writing spreadsheet data. Beside other solutions, e.g. a PEAR-based framework, PHPExcel depends on nothing.*